# How do I display and execute PHP statements when using Neo4J PHP Client?

Tags: php, neo4j, configuration, xampp, cypher

I am trying read/write data in PHP to show Neo4J Graph Databases information. I have followed the steps as shown on (https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client) and after installing Composer, I have tried to configure the settings but all I see is a blank page when running the PHP file using XAMPP server.

I need to basically be able to input and send Cypher queries on PHP that will enter into Neo4J Client.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: I have followed (https://neo4j.com/developer/the-example-project-9/#_neo4j_for_php_developers) still not able to fix this issue. I also installed Bolt but was unable to configure it.

Comment: some source code would be helpful on confidence level

Comment: @GetSet 

`<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addConnection('default', 'http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474') // Example for HTTP connection configuration (port is optional)
    ->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:password@localhost:7687') // Example for BOLT connection configuration (port is optional)
    ->build();`

This is the code that needs to be put in the autoloader once composer is set up. I am unable to get passed this step.

Comment: What is your error/exception stack trace? You may have to turn error reporting on